# Why setx command does not set an user variable?

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

I want to add an user variable using `setx`.
I tried:

```
setx LOL abcd

> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved

echo %LOL%

> %LOL%
```

Why it does not set an user variable? I expected:

```
echo %LOL%

> abcd
```

Comment: SETX modifies the registry so that future sessions will have that environment variable defined.  You are looking for plain SET here.  Type `SETX /?` for help, note bullet 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why setx command does not set an user variable?

Because that is the way it works.

`setx` will change the environment variable you specify for *future* sessions. Use `set` to set for the current and new child processes.